# Read base64 string of png datatype as cv:MAT object in opencv.js using javascript

Tags: javascript, opencv, image-processing, canvas, base64

I am trying to read base64 string as mat object in javascript I tried everything I found on internet and documentation. I tried to load img element and assigned img element src to base64. I also tried getting image data from canvas which has image drawn to cv mat array but still no luck.

approach using image element

```
img.addEventListener(
  "load",
  () => {
    // execute drawImage statements here
  },
  false,
);
img.src = "myImage.png"; // Set source path
src = cv.imread(img)
```

I tried using canvas too like below

```
this.canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(this.video, 0, 0, 
this.video.videoWidth, this.video.videoHeight,0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
let ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
let imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, this.video.videoWidth, this.video.videoHeight);
let src = cv.matFromImageData(imgData);
```

both times src is undefined and I checked canvas has width = 720 and height=480, but src is undefined.
I am used to python not a front-end guy, my knowledge on front-end is limited.
IS there any simple way I can just use base64 string as MAT object using javascript ?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is: timing.

The parameter passed to openCV's `imread()` function must be an instance of `HTMLImageElement` and beside that it also must contain data e.g. the actual imagedata yet. In Javascript however image loading is an asynchronous operation.

Now if you write something like:

```
img.addEventListener(
  "load",
  () => {
    // execute drawImage statements here
  },
  false,
);
img.src = "myImage.png"; // Set source path
src = cv.imread(img)
```

the image won't be loaded yet the time you try to use `cv.imread(img)`.

That's the purpose of the `"load"` event listener. As soon as it fires you know you can work with the image's data. So the only thing you need to do is move the `imread()` call inside the event listener's callback function.

For example:

```js
let img = document.getElementById("myImage");
img.addEventListener(
  "load",
  () => {
    let mat = cv.imread(img);
    console.log(mat);
  },
  false
);
img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
img.src = "https://api.codetabs.com/v1/proxy/?quest=https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300";
```

```html
<script src=" https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/opencv-browser@1.0.0/opencv.min.js "></script>
<img id="myImage">
```